# In SharePoint 2013 How do I single space within a WebPart Content Editor

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My HTML skills are not great.  When I cut and paste a paragraph into a WebPart/Content Editor it double spaces all the lines.  If I try to backspace out the extra line (carriage return) it then brings the line 2 lines above (not the desired 1 line above) and now I have 2 lines of words on 1 line.

Any suggestions..Do I need to try &nbsp ?

Comment: Use "Paste as Plain Text" option.

Answer (score 6):

The SharePoint content editor gives you a double space every time you press **enter**, if you just want a single space press **Shift+Enter**.

This is actually the difference between Paragraphe Break and Line Break

NB: If you use line break both lines will use the same style

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to visualize without a screenshot on what's happening. But I'm assuming you had double spaces created between words in the paragraph after pasting.

**Method #1**: If this is so, and I'm assuming you do not want the formatting of the paragraph from the source, you may want to try pasting into the webpart/content editor box with "Paste as Plain Text".

**Method #2**: If method 1 doesn't work, try to paste the paragraph content into a notepad, then copy the content and paste it into the webpart/content editor.

It could be because of the formatting on the paragraph.